# Add / set Border property for Button/ListBox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

The Button and ListBox code are already using one static resource:

```
<StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical">
     <Button x:Name="ololo1"  Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding CommandDump}" Background="Purple" Foreground="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily-Sketch}">Text</Button>
...
    <ListBox local:ListBoxBehaviors.AutoSizeItemCount="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberPath="Item1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I only need to add this:

```
 <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
```

How to do it ?

I have tryed :

```
 <ListBox ...>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    <!--...-->
</ListBox>
```

for list box but still no good(

Comment: Maybe you could add some more detaitls about your problem

Comment: the problem is - how to set Border properties in <Style> of Button/ListBox

Answer (score 0):

you need to use window/userControl.resources (depends what your using), the following example uses UserControl, to use it for window just change the usercontrol to window:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BorderStyle">     
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3,0,0,0" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
 </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

in your border:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}"/>
```

Comment: shalom, israel. the problem is that I could not set Border in this two controls - there is only BorderBrush and BorderThickness

Comment: ah...and there is no cornerRadius, is this the problem?

Comment: yes. The perfect solution will be to add this corner radius somehow to style but I have tryed one thing for list box (see last edit ) and this not helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this as a global style, just embedd it into the xaml of your `Application` class like this:

```
<Application x:Class="YourNamespace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

            <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Not helped =(( all is the same. Only the main window borders are rounded

Comment: Would you like to set the style global or only to a specific control? Maybe change the `x:Type Border` to `x:Type Button` for testing puropse...

Comment: x:Type Button has no Property="CornerRadius" and listBox has no this property too